# Django Rest Framework - Generate a Token for a non-built-in User model class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I wanted to know if I am able to create a Token for a normal model class. Suppose that I have the following class:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    profile_pic             = models.FileField(upload_to='None/',default='placeholder.jpg')
    joined_date             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
```

Note that my User class does not extend `auth.models.User` .

Now when I use a signal like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Then Django states that `Token.user` is not an instance of `User`. Basically, the same as in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683511/django-auth-token-valueerror-when-assigning-to-user).

From that link above, I learned that my `User` class has to extend the built-in `auth.models.User` class provided by `Django` for authentication.

But I am curious and would like to know if there is a way to generate a Token for classes that do not extend auth.models.User ? Is that possible ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 2):

**#1 approach**

We are trying here to generate tokens. Token, by definition, are randomly generated sequences of chars. Taking inspiration from the rest auth token model, we can have a similar custom model. We will be overriding the save method of this model to generate the key.

```
import binascii
import os

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class NonBuiltInUserToken(models.Model):
    ...
    key: str = models.CharField(_("Key"), max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    user: User = models.OneToOneField(
            User, related_name='auth_token',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            verbose_name=_("User")
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(_("Created"), auto_now_add=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Token")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tokens")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.key:
            self.key = self.generate_key()
        return super(NonBuiltInUserToken, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def generate_key(self):
        return binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

Copied from [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41232811)

**#2 approach**

You can also try to subclass the Token model of the auth token.

```
...
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework.auth_token.models import Token
...

class NonBuiltInUserToken(Token):
        """
        Overrides the Token model to use the
        non-built-in user model
        """
        user = models.OneToOneField(
            User, related_name='auth_token',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            verbose_name=_("User")
        )
```

If we check the `Token` model in the [rest_framework.authtoken.models](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py#L9), we will see that `Token` class is abstract if `rest_framework.authtoken` is not present in the `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
class Meta:
        # Work around for a bug in Django:
        # https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19422
        #
        # Also see corresponding ticket:
        # https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/705
        abstract = 'rest_framework.authtoken' not in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
```

Thus in order to use this token model, you will be required to remove the `rest_framework.authtoken` from the settings.INSTALLED_APPS

Now, you have a new token model for non-build in the user model. You will be using this model in the signals to create tokens.

Comment: Thanks but now I get a FieldError like this: FieldError: Local field 'user' in class 'NonBuiltInUserToken' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'Token'.

Comment: Oh yes!. ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/39278537/6766209. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I copy pasted your solution. But I still get the same error.

Comment: I have updated the answer, after going through the rest_framework source code and some other SO answers